# Problems with Volunteer registration

Tags: civivolunteer

[image]I am just implementing civiVolunteer for a German NGO. We have the issue that a newly registerd volunteer is assigned to all activities in the system which is messing everything. Has anybody else experienced this issue?

Comment: Hi Ulrich, Welcome to civicrm stackexchange. To make it easier for people to help  could include the version of civicrm (including what cms you are using) and what version of CiviVolunteer (since this relates to an extension).

Comment: Sorry Luke, we are using CiviCRM 5.7.2 on Drupal, civiVolonteer 4.7.31-2.3.1